# RewriteRule Conversion

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need help i was rewriting rules from lighthttpd to apache httpd. Though i never used lighthttpd before. i was hoping someone can help me rewriting this code. I kinda suck with Rule system even in apache but not that bad.

```
"^install/?$" => "install.php",

"^/doc/([a-z]+)/?$" => "doc.php?cat=$1",
"^/~([a-z.]+)/doc/([a-z]+)/?$" => "doc.php?project=$1&cat=$2",

"^/~([a-z.]+)/?$" => "index.php?project=$1",
"^/~([a-z.]+)/api/([a-z]+)/?$" => "index.php?project=$1&mode=$2",

"^/all/?$" => "list.php",
"^/api/([a-z]+)/all/?$" => "list.php?mode=$1",
"^/~([a-z.]+)/all/?$" => "list.php?project=$1",
"^/~([a-z.]+)/api/([a-z]+)/all/?$" => "list.php?project=$1&mode=$2",
"^/rss/?$" => "list.php?rss=1",
"^/~([a-z.]+)/rss/?$" => "list.php?project=$1&rss=1",
"^/all/([0-9]+)/?$" => "list.php?page=$1",
"^/api/([a-z]+)/all/([0-9]+)/?$" => "list.php?mode=$1&page=$2",
"^/~([a-z.]+)/all/([0-9]+)/?$" => "list.php?project=$1&page=$2",
"^/~([a-z.]+)/api/([a-z]+)/all/([0-9]+)/?$" => "list.php?project=$1&mode=$2&page=$3",

"^/([0-9]+)/?$" => "show.php?id=$1",
"^/~([a-z.]+)/([0-9]+)/?$" => "show.php?project=$1&id=$2",
"^/([0-9]+)/([a-z|A-Z]+)/?$" => "show.php?id=$1&mode=$2",
"^/~([a-z.]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z|A-Z]+)/?$" => "show.php?project=$1&id=$2&mode=$3",
"^/api/([a-z|A-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$" => "show.php?mode=$1&id=$2",
"^/~([a-z.]+)/api/([a-z|A-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$" => "show.php?project=$1&mode=$2&id=$3",
"^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$" => "show.php?id=$1&hash=$2",
"^/~([a-z.]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$" => "show.php?project=$1&id=$2&hash=$3",
"^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z|A-Z]+)/?$" =/> "show.php?id=$1&hash=$2&mode=$3",
"^/~([a-z.]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z|A-Z]+)/?$" => "show.php?project=$1&id=$2&hash=$3&mode=$4",
"^/api/([a-z|A-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$" => "show.php?mode=$1&id=$2&hash=$3",
"^/~([a-z.]+)/api/([a-z|A-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$" => "show.php?project=$1&mode=$2&id=$3&hash=$4",
"^/api/([a-z|A-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$" => "show.php?mode=$1&id=$2&hash=$3&password=$4",
"^/~([a-z.]+)/api/([a-z|A-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$" => "show.php?project=$1&mode=$2&id=$3&hash=$4&password=$5"
```

and the only thing i converted was the first line

```
RewriteRule ^install/.* install.php
```

Comment: yes i am familiar with regex

Comment: Though i never used regex with RewriteRule. And i'm not a lighthttpd user too. So im kinda confused on how they write their. url rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So

```
"^install/?$" => "install.php"
```

turns into

```
RewriteRule ^install/?$ install.php [L]
```

and

```
"^/doc/([a-z]+)/?$" => "doc.php?cat=$1"
```

turns into

```
RewriteRule ^doc/([a-z]+)/?$ doc.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

and

```
"^/~([a-z.]+)/doc/([a-z]+)/?$" => "doc.php?project=$1&cat=$2",
```

turns into

```
RewriteRule ^~([a-z.]+)/doc/([a-z]+)/?$ doc.php?project=$1&cat=$2 [L]
```

and

```
"^/~([a-z.]+)/?$" => "index.php?project=$1",
```

turns into

```
RewriteRule ^~([a-z.]+)/?$ index.php?project=$1 [L]
```

etc.

Comment: imma give try this. it might take a while

Comment: I think there is a typo in the second `RewriteRule` (see the quotation mark).

Comment: excuse me. I tried to follow what you did but. some of it didn't work
this is the list of didn't work. can you give me a format for some of this? http://pastebin.com/cbgV0Lc7